# Group SVG in TornadoFX

Tags: tornadofx

I'm trying to implement a SVG as a background image for my Stackpane that's composed of 4 separate closed paths. When I export it from Illustrator as a SVG I get this:

```
<g>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M948.35,285.18a43.42,43.42,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.76,173.76,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,862.47,224a69.87,69.87,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.38,201.38,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.62,77.62,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.76,173.76,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,638.25,224a69.86,69.86,0,0,0-12.41-3.39A79,79,0,0,0,612,219.45a74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.61,77.61,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.8,173.8,0,0,1,456,258.05c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,414,224a69.88,69.88,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24A201.34,201.34,0,0,0,320,257.57c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.6,77.6,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84A108.6,108.6,0,0,0,210,235.66,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,189.81,224a69.89,69.89,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.78,74.78,0,0,0-23.5,3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.57,77.57,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.55,38.55,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,15.65,15.65,0,0,0,0,31.3A74.78,74.78,0,0,0,75,312.88a70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.57,77.57,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.55,38.55,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.77,173.77,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.62,108.62,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.4,88.4,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.33,201.33,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1,7.53,6A173.76,173.76,0,0,1,656,277.88c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1A88.37,88.37,0,0,0,776,295.54a201.34,201.34,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.55,77.55,0,0,1,7.37-6.82A42.3,42.3,0,0,1,821,253.32a38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.68,47.68,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.76,173.76,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.62,108.62,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.86,69.86,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,15.65,15.65,0,1,0,0-31.3Z" transform="translate(-35.81 -219.45)"/>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M948.35,440.14a43.42,43.42,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.75,173.75,0,0,1,904.41,413c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.55,108.55,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.63,73.63,0,0,0,862.47,379a69.85,69.85,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18A74.77,74.77,0,0,0,812.75,378a70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.4,88.4,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.37,201.37,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.57,77.57,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.91,38.91,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,680.19,413c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,638.25,379a69.86,69.86,0,0,0-12.41-3.39A79,79,0,0,0,612,374.41,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,588.53,378a70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.34,201.34,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.56,77.56,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.73,173.73,0,0,1,456,413c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,414,379a69.88,69.88,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18A74.77,74.77,0,0,0,364.31,378a70.28,70.28,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24A201.35,201.35,0,0,0,320,412.53c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.76,173.76,0,0,1,231.75,413c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84A108.62,108.62,0,0,0,210,390.62,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,189.81,379a69.89,69.89,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.78,74.78,0,0,0-23.5,3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.61,77.61,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,15.65,15.65,0,0,0,0,31.3A74.78,74.78,0,0,0,75,467.84a70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.6,77.6,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.32,201.32,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.58,77.58,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.58,77.58,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,656,432.84c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1A88.38,88.38,0,0,0,776,450.5a201.3,201.3,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82A42.3,42.3,0,0,1,821,408.28a38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.75,173.75,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,15.65,15.65,0,1,0,0-31.3Z" transform="translate(-35.81 -219.45)"/>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M948.35,595.1a43.42,43.42,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.75,173.75,0,0,1,904.41,568c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.55,108.55,0,0,0-10.36-9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0-20.17-11.65,69.85,69.85,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18A74.77,74.77,0,0,0,812.75,533a70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.4,88.4,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.37,201.37,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.57,77.57,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.91,38.91,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,680.19,568c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0-20.17-11.65,69.86,69.86,0,0,0-12.41-3.39A79,79,0,0,0,612,529.37,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,588.53,533a70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.34,201.34,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.56,77.56,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.73,173.73,0,0,1,456,568c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,414,533.93a69.88,69.88,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18A74.77,74.77,0,0,0,364.31,533a70.28,70.28,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24A201.35,201.35,0,0,0,320,567.49c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79A38.53,38.53,0,0,1,284,594.4a47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.76,173.76,0,0,1,231.75,568c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84A108.62,108.62,0,0,0,210,545.58a73.64,73.64,0,0,0-20.18-11.64,69.89,69.89,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.78,74.78,0,0,0-23.5,3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.61,77.61,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,15.65,15.65,0,0,0,0,31.3A74.78,74.78,0,0,0,75,622.8a70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.6,77.6,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.32,201.32,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44A77.58,77.58,0,0,1,361,570a42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.58,77.58,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,656,587.8c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1A88.38,88.38,0,0,0,776,605.45a201.3,201.3,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82A42.3,42.3,0,0,1,821,563.23a38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.75,173.75,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,15.65,15.65,0,1,0,0-31.3Z" transform="translate(-35.81 -219.45)"/>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M948.35,750.06a43.42,43.42,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.75,173.75,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.55,108.55,0,0,0-10.36-9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0-20.17-11.65,69.85,69.85,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61A70.3,70.3,0,0,0,796,696a88.4,88.4,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.37,201.37,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44A77.57,77.57,0,0,1,751,740.7a42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.91,38.91,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.72,173.72,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0-20.17-11.65,69.86,69.86,0,0,0-12.41-3.39A79,79,0,0,0,612,684.33a74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.34,201.34,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.56,77.56,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.73,173.73,0,0,1,456,722.93c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,414,688.89a69.88,69.88,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61A70.28,70.28,0,0,0,347.6,696a88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24A201.35,201.35,0,0,0,320,722.45c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7A43.43,43.43,0,0,1,262,748a38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.76,173.76,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84A108.62,108.62,0,0,0,210,700.54a73.64,73.64,0,0,0-20.18-11.64,69.89,69.89,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.78,74.78,0,0,0-23.5,3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.61,77.61,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,15.65,15.65,0,0,0,0,31.3A74.78,74.78,0,0,0,75,777.75a70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.6,77.6,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.32,201.32,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44A77.58,77.58,0,0,1,361,725a42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.58,77.58,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,656,742.76c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1A88.38,88.38,0,0,0,776,760.41a201.3,201.3,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82A42.3,42.3,0,0,1,821,718.19a38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.75,173.75,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,15.65,15.65,0,1,0,0-31.3Z" transform="translate(-35.81 -219.45)"/>
</g>
```

the `d=""` obviously being the relevant part of the SVG data, along with the `translate(x,y)`. As far as I'm aware, TornadoFX only supports the ability to add a single string to a `svgpath` node. Is there a way that I'm not aware of to use the SVG grouping functionality in TornadoFX, or do I need to make 4 separate `svgpath` nodes and translate them manually?

something like:

```
svgpath(//group of svgs here) {
  addClass(svgstyle)
}
```

as opposed to:

```
vbox {
  svgpath("first svg path string"){
    addClass(svgstyle)
  }

  svgpath("second svg path string"){
    addClass(svgstyle)
    translateY = -20.0
  }

  //etc
}
```

I would like to keep the original spacing and whatnot from the SVG export, but am unsure if there is a TornadoFX functionality that will do this for me, or if I have to manually do this.

Thanks for any help!

**edit:** I realised that I don't need to translate manually because the starting path point is different for each path, but I would still like to know if there is any sort of "group svg" functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you put your paths in a Group. If you want to add a class to all of the paths within a Group, you can add the paths first, then add the class directly to the children property of the group:

```
class SVGView : View() {
    override val root = stackpane {
        group {
            svgpath("M948.35,285.18a43.42,43.42,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.76,173.76,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,862.47,224a69.87,69.87,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.38,201.38,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.62,77.62,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.76,173.76,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,638.25,224a69.86,69.86,0,0,0-12.41-3.39A79,79,0,0,0,612,219.45a74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.61,77.61,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.8,173.8,0,0,1,456,258.05c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,414,224a69.88,69.88,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24A201.34,201.34,0,0,0,320,257.57c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.6,77.6,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84A108.6,108.6,0,0,0,210,235.66,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,189.81,224a69.89,69.89,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.78,74.78,0,0,0-23.5,3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.57,77.57,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.55,38.55,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,15.65,15.65,0,0,0,0,31.3A74.78,74.78,0,0,0,75,312.88a70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.57,77.57,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.55,38.55,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.77,173.77,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.62,108.62,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.4,88.4,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.33,201.33,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1,7.53,6A173.76,173.76,0,0,1,656,277.88c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1A88.37,88.37,0,0,0,776,295.54a201.34,201.34,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.55,77.55,0,0,1,7.37-6.82A42.3,42.3,0,0,1,821,253.32a38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.68,47.68,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.76,173.76,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.62,108.62,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.86,69.86,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,15.65,15.65,0,1,0,0-31.3Z")
            svgpath("M948.35,440.14a43.42,43.42,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.75,173.75,0,0,1,904.41,413c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.55,108.55,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.63,73.63,0,0,0,862.47,379a69.85,69.85,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18A74.77,74.77,0,0,0,812.75,378a70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.4,88.4,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.37,201.37,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.57,77.57,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.91,38.91,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,680.19,413c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,638.25,379a69.86,69.86,0,0,0-12.41-3.39A79,79,0,0,0,612,374.41,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,588.53,378a70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.34,201.34,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.56,77.56,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.73,173.73,0,0,1,456,413c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,414,379a69.88,69.88,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18A74.77,74.77,0,0,0,364.31,378a70.28,70.28,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24A201.35,201.35,0,0,0,320,412.53c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.76,173.76,0,0,1,231.75,413c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84A108.62,108.62,0,0,0,210,390.62,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,189.81,379a69.89,69.89,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.78,74.78,0,0,0-23.5,3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.61,77.61,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,15.65,15.65,0,0,0,0,31.3A74.78,74.78,0,0,0,75,467.84a70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.6,77.6,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.32,201.32,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.58,77.58,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.58,77.58,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,656,432.84c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1A88.38,88.38,0,0,0,776,450.5a201.3,201.3,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82A42.3,42.3,0,0,1,821,408.28a38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.75,173.75,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,15.65,15.65,0,1,0,0-31.3Z")
            svgpath("M948.35,595.1a43.42,43.42,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.75,173.75,0,0,1,904.41,568c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.55,108.55,0,0,0-10.36-9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0-20.17-11.65,69.85,69.85,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18A74.77,74.77,0,0,0,812.75,533a70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.4,88.4,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.37,201.37,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.57,77.57,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.91,38.91,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,680.19,568c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0-20.17-11.65,69.86,69.86,0,0,0-12.41-3.39A79,79,0,0,0,612,529.37,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,588.53,533a70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.34,201.34,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.56,77.56,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.73,173.73,0,0,1,456,568c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,414,533.93a69.88,69.88,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18A74.77,74.77,0,0,0,364.31,533a70.28,70.28,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24A201.35,201.35,0,0,0,320,567.49c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79A38.53,38.53,0,0,1,284,594.4a47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.76,173.76,0,0,1,231.75,568c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84A108.62,108.62,0,0,0,210,545.58a73.64,73.64,0,0,0-20.18-11.64,69.89,69.89,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.78,74.78,0,0,0-23.5,3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.61,77.61,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,15.65,15.65,0,0,0,0,31.3A74.78,74.78,0,0,0,75,622.8a70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.6,77.6,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.32,201.32,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44A77.58,77.58,0,0,1,361,570a42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.58,77.58,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,656,587.8c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1A88.38,88.38,0,0,0,776,605.45a201.3,201.3,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82A42.3,42.3,0,0,1,821,563.23a38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.75,173.75,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,15.65,15.65,0,1,0,0-31.3Z")
            svgpath("M948.35,750.06a43.42,43.42,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.24,57.24,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.75,173.75,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.55,108.55,0,0,0-10.36-9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0-20.17-11.65,69.85,69.85,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61A70.3,70.3,0,0,0,796,696a88.4,88.4,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.37,201.37,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44A77.57,77.57,0,0,1,751,740.7a42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.91,38.91,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.72,173.72,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0-20.17-11.65,69.86,69.86,0,0,0-12.41-3.39A79,79,0,0,0,612,684.33a74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.34,201.34,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.56,77.56,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1-13.73-2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1-7.53-6A173.73,173.73,0,0,1,456,722.93c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84a108.6,108.6,0,0,0-10.36-9.55A73.64,73.64,0,0,0,414,688.89a69.88,69.88,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0-23.49,3.61A70.28,70.28,0,0,0,347.6,696a88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24A201.35,201.35,0,0,0,320,722.45c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7A43.43,43.43,0,0,1,262,748a38.92,38.92,0,0,1-9.3-4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1-7.53-6,173.76,173.76,0,0,1-13.38-14.56c-3.51-4.12-7.22-8.49-11.41-12.84A108.62,108.62,0,0,0,210,700.54a73.64,73.64,0,0,0-20.18-11.64,69.89,69.89,0,0,0-12.41-3.39,79,79,0,0,0-13.81-1.18,74.78,74.78,0,0,0-23.5,3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0-16.71,8.1,88.38,88.38,0,0,0-11.67,9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0-15.88,17.17c-3.53,4.14-6.85,8-10.14,11.44a77.61,77.61,0,0,1-7.37,6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1-11.63,6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1-6.87,1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1-8.35.7,15.65,15.65,0,0,0,0,31.3A74.78,74.78,0,0,0,75,777.75a70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.6,77.6,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.54,38.54,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.23,57.23,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.29,70.29,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.37,88.37,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.32,201.32,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44A77.58,77.58,0,0,1,361,725a42.31,42.31,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.93,38.93,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.22,57.22,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.78,173.78,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.59,108.59,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1,88.39,88.39,0,0,0,11.67-9.24,201.35,201.35,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.58,77.58,0,0,1,7.37-6.82,42.3,42.3,0,0,1,11.63-6.79,38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.7,47.7,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.43,43.43,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6A173.72,173.72,0,0,1,656,742.76c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.58,108.58,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.64,73.64,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.88,69.88,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,74.77,74.77,0,0,0,23.49-3.61,70.3,70.3,0,0,0,16.71-8.1A88.38,88.38,0,0,0,776,760.41a201.3,201.3,0,0,0,15.88-17.17c3.53-4.14,6.85-8,10.14-11.44a77.59,77.59,0,0,1,7.37-6.82A42.3,42.3,0,0,1,821,718.19a38.53,38.53,0,0,1,6.87-1.87,47.69,47.69,0,0,1,8.35-.7,43.42,43.42,0,0,1,13.73,2,38.92,38.92,0,0,1,9.3,4.53,57.21,57.21,0,0,1,7.53,6,173.75,173.75,0,0,1,13.38,14.56c3.51,4.12,7.22,8.49,11.41,12.84a108.57,108.57,0,0,0,10.36,9.55,73.63,73.63,0,0,0,20.17,11.65,69.87,69.87,0,0,0,12.41,3.39,79,79,0,0,0,13.81,1.18,15.65,15.65,0,1,0,0-31.3Z")
            children.addClass(svgstyle)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have your paths in a list, you can iterate over them instead:

```
class SVGView : View() {
    val paths = listOf("...", "...", "...", "...")

    override val root = stackpane {
        group {
            paths.forEach {
                svgpath(it) {
                    addClass(svgstyle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aha! I did not see the Group node. thank you so much, this is a lot cleaner than what i was doing haha